# How can I use assert in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to use `assert` because in Prolog we cannot assign values to variable twice using `is`. So how can I do that? Below is what I want to implement-how can I add `assert` in that code?

```
main:-
  X1 is 3,
  X2 is 3,
  A is 1,
 ( X1=X2 -> A is 2 , write(A)
 ; X1=X3 -> A is 3 , write(A)
 ).
```

I want to update the value of A in the if clause.How can I do it using `assert`?

Comment: What you are trying to do is probably done better without any asserts. If you want to learn how to use `assert`, see the documentation.

Comment: @Boris How can I do it without assert as I cannot assign values to variable twice.That is why this code is giving error.

Comment: I agree with Boris; use of `assert` is probably unwarranted here.

Comment: @sharky I think I was not able to explain my real problem.I am using value of A earlier in my rest of the code.In here I want to increment its value by one whenever this conditon is true.Then I will call the predicate again with new value of A using recursion.

Comment: Then I recommend using a new argument to your recursive function to capture the latest value of `A`, instead of using the fact database and `assert/retract`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple of things you need to notice:

You don't have to use `retractall()` twice. You can use it once at the beginning of `main/0` :

```
main:-retractall(value_A(_)),
       X1 is 3,X2 is 3,A is 1,
      ( X1=X2 -> asserta(value_A(2))
      ; X1=X3 -> asserta(value_A(3))
      ),value_A(X),write(X).
```

Also, `assert` isn't Prolog ISO; it doesn't work in all the versions of Prolog. It would be better to use `asserta` which is.

Also, you might need to declare the dynamic variables in Prolog. You can do that at the top of your program like:

```
:- dynamic value_A/1.

main:-retractall(value_A(_)),
 X1 is 3,X2 is 3,A is 1,
 ( X1=X2 -> asserta(value_A(2))
 ; X1=X3 -> asserta(value_A(3))
 ),value_A(X),write(X).
```

When you see something like `:-something` at the source code of a Prolog program, it means that this is something that will be executed when the program is started.

Answer (score 1):

Simply let `A` be *unbound* prior to the `if-then` construct, as follows:

```
   main :-
     X1 is 3,
     X2 is 3,
     ( X1=X2 -> A is 2
     ; X1=X3 -> A is 3
     ),
     write(A).
```

**EDIT:**

OP (noobcoder) wants to use `assert` regardless. Here's how, if `A` represents a global variable.

`assert` is used to capture new facts in the database. If you're updating these facts, you may also want to `retract` old values. For example:

```
   main :-
     X1 is 3,
     X2 is 3,
     ( X1=X2 -> retractall(val_of_a(_)), assert(val_of_a(2))
     ; X1=X3 -> retractall(val_of_a(_)), assert(val_of_a(3))
     ),
     val_of_a(A),
     write(A).
```

Comment: No this was just an example.In my whole code I have used A earlier and I want to increment its value everytime this condition is true.

Comment: Then the example is misleading, because you refer to the code shown.

Comment: Prolog does not support global variables. The closest you'll come is facts in the database, such as `val_of_a/1` in my answer, which you can update dynamically using assert/retract predicates. This is generally considered a bad way to program in Prolog. Ideally, you should aim to use local variables instead, if possible.

Comment: I have done this dynamically `:- dynamic val_of_a/1.`.When I do `assert(val_of_a(1)),` I am getting this error-
 `is/2: Arithmetic: val_of_a/0 is not a function`

Comment: This is because you're incorrectly using the `is` function to update the value of the _predicate_ `val_of_a`. To give it an incremented value, try `NewA is A + 1, assert(val_of_a(NewA))`.

Comment: I want to give initial value 1 to it.So I am doing this before the if condtion `New1 is 1,retractall(val_of_a(_)),assert(val_of_a(New1)),` But still I am getting the same error